# Windows Media Center playing iTunes Video

Tags: windows-8, itunes, windows-media-center

I have a video which I've bought from iTunes (stored locally), I've added it to the Media Centre library (in Windows 8 Professional) and it can't play it.

The warning says: Windows media center cannot find the specified file.  Make sure that the path is typed correctly.  If it is the file does not exist at the specified location or the computer where it is stored is offline.

It's stored locally so I don't believe this is the error, as a m4v and as it's a direct download I have no doubt that it's protected.

I was under the impression that Media Center would be able to play the file?  What's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that the file you are trying to play is of a foreign codec to Media Center. You need to install a codec pack such as CCCP (http://www.cccp-project.net/) or K-Lite ([http://codecguide.com/download_kl.htm](http://codecguide.com/download_kl.htm/)). Is it possible you could clarify what file/extension the video is?

The other possibility is that the file has DRM on it, which means you wont be able to play it anywhere but iTunes (which is a real pain).

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to the world of DRM.

Unless you used *Requiem* you probably can play it only in iTunes.